# Hadoop - checksum while reading file from client

Tags: bigdata, apache-hadoop

In hadoop , if i want to read a file from client , the class DFSInputStream enters in action.

About this, my textbook says

**The DFSInputStream also verifies checksums for the data transferred to it from the datanode.
If a corrupted block is found, the DFSInputStream attempts to read a replica of the block from another datanode; it also reports the corrupted block to the namenode.**

My questions are :
1) What's the meaning in saying that the data is trasferred to DFSInputStream ?
 Am i wrong, or the client communicates directly with the datanode ?

2)If the checksum shows that the transfer of a block has going wrong, why does the DFSInputStream request this block from another datanode instead of trying again with the datanode that generated the corrupted block ?